# CSS3 transition broken, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have a working transition and a broken transition, as far as I can tell I'm doing the same thing on both.
main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="button"><span class="button-content">transformer</span></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
#content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
}
#content:hover {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
}

.button {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
}
.button:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
.button-content {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

The button transitions nicely when hovered over, but the content div changes size instantly with no transition! I'm at a loss.

Comment: My web browser is Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) for Ubuntu.

Comment: Define height: auto; for the #content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the height and width for the #content div before hover takes place are not defined. The buttons dimensions are defined.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I have to wait 9 minutes until accepting your answer.